# convert array to observable array

Tags: knockout.js, observable

Is there any way to convert observable to observable array?

I am asking this because there is one function in my code which expect observable array because the function uses `ko.utils.arrayForEach`

I have try to google but couldnt find anything.

**Update**

i checked what i am passing using `var test = isObservable(item)`. its not observable that i am passing because i get false in variable `test` Its normal array.

So i want to convert array to observable array

Comment: Also as a note ko.utils.arrayForEach doesn't require an observable array.  You could also just say $.each instead if you wanted to

Answer (score 1):

This question doesn't make a ton of sense to me, but here goes -

To convert an array to an observable array, do this -

```
var normalArray = ['1', '2']
normalArray = ko.observableArray(normalArray);
// normalArray is now an observableArray
```

Comment: i get error "The argument passed when initializing an observable array must be an array, or null, or undefined."

Comment: Are you sure it is an array?  Sounds like its not.

Comment: When i see in debug mode what i pass is of type object anonymus function

Comment: I think i get json object with this part "Methods,EntityAspect,prototype".

Answer (score 0):

you can use convert normal array to observable array using`ko.observableArray()`

```
var SimpleListModel = function(items) {
    this.items = ko.observableArray(items);
    this.itemToAdd = ko.observable("");
    this.addItem = function() {
        if (this.itemToAdd() != "") {
            this.items.push(this.itemToAdd()); // Adds the item. Writing to the "items" observableArray causes any associated UI to update.
            this.itemToAdd(""); // Clears the text box, because it's bound to the "itemToAdd" observable
        }
    }.bind(this);  // Ensure that "this" is always this view model
};

ko.applyBindings(new SimpleListModel(["Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma"]));
```

working example http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/bxfXd/